# Design Inputs on .Net MVC Application Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

Hope you are doing Great.

I needed an Expert advice about my below design. 
Actually, We have an application built in .NET MVC. it’s current backend is class library project and hundreds of users are using it. But unfortunately the class library’s code is too much cluttered. 
We intend to add new functionality for the same and I do have opportunity to add a new component to not to increase complexity in class library.

Couple of Considerations
We soon plan to extend the application to be used by Thousand of users 
Also, In Near future, we intend to build App(s) for our end users.

So what could be better option to add as a new component
1) Adding more code in existing class library
2) Adding an API

Also, what is latest trend for back end components ? using Class library or API

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

API & Class Library both can be used for backend development.
In your case, API is good option because if number of users increases, You can host API on other server with minimum changes. You can not host dll on other machine.
API can be deployed independently but dll not. In today's world, People mostly uses API as it can be consumed by mobile APP(s) and other front ends.
So if your are planning to mobo apps then API can reusable.
In the end, both are just different choices with different set of advantages & disadvantages.